# Why is 'transparent' tactic ‘‘counterproductive and contrary to one’s belief in the First Amendment’?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In New Yorker’s article (August 6) titled, ‘Bezos and the Washington Post: A skeptical view,’
the writer, John Cassidy wraps up his article with the following statement:

> Will he (Bezos) be ordering his editors to publish articles defending
>   Amazon’s business tactics and criticizing those who question them? - -
>   -. **Such a tactic would be transparent, counterproductive**, **and,** quite possibly, **contrary to his belief in the First Amendment**. But through
>   the editorial columns of the Post, -- he will be able to have his
>   voice heard much more clearly. And that, surely, must be worth
>   something to him. Two hundred and fifty million dollars, perhaps?
>    http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/johncassidy/2013/08/bezos-and-the-washington-post-a-skeptical-view.html

I stumbled with the line, “Such a tactic would be transparent, counterproductive, and contrary to his belief in the First Amendment.”

Why “transparent tactic,” that is thought to be very productive and commendable as against opaque intent, or cover-up attempts and tactics familiar with political, business scandals, can be “counterproductive and contrary to the belief in the First Amendment” as well? I’m afraid I’m reading the sentence in too immature way, and perhaps nitpicking.

What does ‘transparent’ here mean? Would you clarify why ‘transparent’ is laid in parallel with ‘counterproductive’ and ‘contrary to the belief in the freedom of speech” as a business tactic, or an executive order?

Comment: A *transparent tactic* doesn't mean one which is "thought to be very productive and commendable". It just means people can *eadily see* the motivation for the tactic (in context, usually a *self-serving* and *dishonourable* motivation). This has no direct connection with *counterproductive* (except that sometimes, if people see dishonourable motives in someone's tactics, they may make deliberate efforts to prevent the tactics from working).

Comment: affirming the comment by @FumbleFingers, the reason "transparency" is normally treated as a virtue is that if one strives to make all of their intentions public, then they have a strong interest in possessing only good intentions. being "transparent" encourages good behavior, but only if you would feel shame at having your ill intentions exposed.

Comment: @jlovegren: Agreed, "transparency" on its own is normally considered a virtue. I'm not sure "tactic" necessarily has overriding positive or negative associations, but I think "transparent tactics" would almost *always* be a negative assessment. Even if the person using those tactics genuinely believed his motives were honourable (and thus felt no shame on having them known to all), if someone else called them "transparent" it's unlikely they'd be endorsing the tactician's motivation.

Comment: @ Yoichi: Also note that a "transparent tactic" isn't the opposite of a "cover-up". The specific actual *purpose* of a cover-up is to conceal something. But a transparent tactic could be intended to achieve anything at all (though probably *not* transparency! :).

Comment: FumbleFingers. Glad to hear from you after a while. Maybe this can be a comparative cultural issue. We Japanese have a positive image to the word, ‘transparent’ by using it in the way of ‘transparent policy (no political bargaining / trick), transparent accounting, transparent perspective (of economy), and transparent water (pure and hygienic), while we have a negative image to ‘not transparent – opaqueness, in the way as opaque (uncertain) prospect of economy, opaque management (lacking corporate compliance), opaque remark (muddy message).

Comment: Cont. From your comment, it seems no such positive / negative image is involved in ‘transparent / not transparent’ in English, and just being neutral.

Comment: Yoichi, I hope you will not mind if I reply to an 11 month old comment which I am discovering for the first time. 'Transparent' is a neutral substitute for 'clear' which often has a positive connotation or metaphorical use. For example, "clear water" connotes pure & hygienic where "transparent water" would not. Transparent cannot substitute for all meanings of clear. A "clear head" means a mind free from confusion, and a "clear perspective" on a subject means a valid point of view, but "transparent head" and "transparent perspective" do not have idiomatic meanings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassidy's sentence is something of a mash-up, and needs to be pulled apart to understand it.

- He's using *[transparent](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/transparent)* in the sense of *obvious* (as in a *transparent lie*).
- Jeff Bezos "ordering his editors to publish articles defending Amazon’s business tactics and criticizing those who question them" would be *counterproductive* because it would likely have the *opposite* effect on the Post's readers, who would then criticize Amazon's business tactics, and defend those who question them.
- As I understand the [First Amendment](http://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/first_amendment), which guarantees the right of freedom of speech, it allows individuals to express themselves without interference or constraint *by the government*. Cassidy seems to be applying it to a more general sense of freedom of speech for Amazon's would-be critics.

So Cassidy is arguing that Jeff Bezos would avoid the tactic of using his ownership of the *Washington Post* to quash Amazon's critics by publishing articles against them because it would be obvious, would turn the Post's readers against Amazon instead, and conflict with what Cassidy perceives to be Bezos' political beliefs.

Cassidy is instead concluding that, "through the ready access to powerful people that being the owner of the newspaper brings, [Bezos] will be able to have his voice heard much more clearly," and that that position in itself makes ownership of the *Washington Post* worthwhile for Jeff Bezos.

Comment: A very good answer. I’d add that the author is trying to lessen the sting of the witty question at the end and by mentioning the possibility of Bezos’ altruistic motivation. I think the paragraph is a little clunky: He’s probably not buying a big megaphone but why else would he spend $250M?